# Is there a way to conditionally call a function with one line of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, ecmascript-5

I would like an elegant way to only execute a function if some condition is met. Two options that I know of are if conditions and the tertiary operator.

**if**

```
if(headerExists($listview) === false)
        addHeader($listview, template);
```

**tertiary**

```
    headerExists($listview) ? null : addHeader($listview);
```

To me, the if makes the logic a little harder to understand when you look at the function as a whole. The tertiary function seems smart but you never see it anywhere and having to declare null is explicitly wasted space.

Comment: I use the ternary plenty of times in the project I am currently on. It's very condensed and saves space. As long as you understand your code and it works, why not?

Answer (score 3):

The third option is to (ab)use the [short-circuit behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of the [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

```
!headerExists($listview) && addHeader($listview, template);
// or
headerExists($listview) || addHeader($listview, template);
```

However, this is only a minification technique (which doesn't even make the code a lot shorter). Use an if-statement for readability reasons, if you want without a block and in one line:

```
if (!headerExists($listview)) addHeader($listview, template);
```

Comment: Ah, idioms... It's like The New Yorker of JavaScript